# Unable to find render using OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am using a mac, and am trying to render the environment from open ai's gym

```py
import gym
env= gym.make('CartPole-v1')
img = env.render()
```

```
ImportError: Can't find framework /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError: 
    Error occurred while running `from pyglet.gl import *`
    HINT: make sure you have OpenGL install. On Ubuntu, you can run 'apt-get install python-opengl'.
    If you're running on a server, you may need a virtual frame buffer; something like this should work:
    'xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24" python <your_script.py>'
```

Despite the fact that when I navigate to that directory (Framewords) I can directly see OpenGL.framework

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: There's an [official thread](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/2101) on this exact issue from the openai gym github, did that not solve the issue for you?

Comment: This led me to my solution, I was unaware this thread existed. Thankyou!

Comment: Glad that was helpful. Always good to Google your errors before posting here, that's all I did.